# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error in gelRunVertexSubmitARM

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, isgl3d

In my project I am using a storyboard.

There is view controller `MyViewController`. `MyViewController` has button, on click of button it opens a `Isgl3DViewController`.

`Isgl3dViewController` has an animated 3d object. `Isgl3dViewController` also has a Close button, which dismisses the `Isgl3dViewController` and moves to `MyViewController`.

Now, when I am doing this first time, everything is working fine. I am able to see animated object and able to move `MyViewController` on click of Close Button.

But second time, when I click on MyViewController's button to display animation, Application being crashed again and again.

When it's working fine in first time then why app crashes in second time? Please help me out this.

For Reference I am attaching screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: can you show the log error?

Comment: unfortunately there is no log error. App crashes directly with out any log.

Comment: try to add an exceptions Breackpoint

Comment: A screenshot of the disassembly of a library function won't help anyone diagnose your problem. Looking at the call stack would be a least a bit more informative (what code of yours is calling something that's calling into `gleRunVertexSubmitARM`?). You can also try looking at your app in Instruments (OpenGL ES Analysis) or capturing a frame in Xcode (before it crashes) -- one of those tools might spot something that's going wrong before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, in my case because i add UI elements over the isgl3dview.

my workaround was substitute the UIView by a HUD.